# Linux script that scans the network

Tags: linux, bash

i have a question i want to run a script that scans my network and that i can see with devices are up in my network. I want to paste some arguments also in the script

When i run the script: ./ping.sh --xx-YY 20 50

Output:

```
192.168.0.20 is down 

192.168.0.21 is up
```

..................................

```
192.168.0.50 is up
```

the argument -t , counts 200 by the last digit for ex. 
./ping.sh -t 20
output: 192.168.0.220 is up

**But my problem is de argument --up en -mac 
I want when i run the script ./ping.sh --up , its only display the computers there are up** 
**And the argument - mac is also a problem when I run the script i want to display the ip addresses and de mac address after the computers are ping**

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ -n "$@" ]]
do
    case "$1" in

    -h|--help)
    Extension=1
    shift
    ;;

    -XX-YY)
    Extension=2
    shift
    min=$1
    shift
    max=$1
    shift

    ;;

    --up)
    Extension=3
    shift
    end=$1
    shift
    ;;

    -t)
    Extension=4
    shift
    count=$(($1+200))
    shift
    ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$Extension" -eq 1 ] ; then

    echo "dit is de help"

fi


if [ "$Extension" -eq 2 ] ; then

for ((n=$min ; n<=$max ; n+=1))
do
ip=192.168.0.$n
if ping -c 1 -w 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> logping.txt; then
echo "${ip} is up"
else
echo "${ip} is down"
fi
done


fi

if [ "$Extension" -eq 3 ] ; then


                ip=192.168.0.$end
                if ping -c 1 -w 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> /logping.txt; then
                        echo "${ip} is up"

                fi

fi

if [ "$Extension" -eq 4 ] ; then

ip=192.168.0.$count
if ping -c 1 -t 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> logping.txt; then
echo "${ip} is up"
else
echo "${ip} is down"
fi
fi
```

Comment: Don't crosspost to 4 sites (SE, Ask, SU and U&L). This is generally considered to be rude and inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel - [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/) does that quite nicely. How about

```
nmap -sP -n -r 192.168.1.0/24 | grep "is up"
```

Vary the IP range as per your needs. If you omit the `grep`, the Ping scan will show the MAC addresses (provided you're on the same link as the interface), eg.:

```
...
Host 192.168.1.249 is up (0.00011s latency).
MAC Address: 00:08:9B:BF:A9:FC (ICP Electronics)
Host 192.168.1.251 is up (0.0035s latency).
MAC Address: 00:27:0C:5A:5B:A8 (Unknown)
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: Yes but thats just my problem i stuck for implement this in my script, when i do it i have errors..

Comment: Can you show me how to implement the nmap in my script please ?

Comment: Why use a script that simply wraps `nmap`? Everything you try to do in your script is a one-liner with `nmap`- why do you need the extra complexity here?

Comment: when i run the script ./ping.sh -mac 10 20
I want as output
192.168.0.1 is up and his mac address
192.168.0.2 is down no mac addres display 

When the ping is succesfully i want to display the ip addres of the host and his mac addres

Comment: fetch mac address from `arp -a` arp like a CAM table in the switch store source mac and destination mac you can fetch any destination ip up host which try to ping inside your network .